# Babel 7 Upgrading creating error: "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'"

Tags: babeljs

I'm in the process of upgrading from babel 6 to babel 7. Some of my old tests using chai, sinon, and enzyme come up with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

I do have some code that is using "require" instead of "export" and I know that the babel 7 documentation says that you might need to use "require().default" instead. But that doesn't seem to be helping.(Or I just need to finish putting defaults everywhere and calling them before any the errors will go away). Does anyone else have experience with this issue?

Comment: post babel config

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try not to mix `require / module.exports` and `import / export`, ensure to be consistent with one.

Comment: You're right! That's what the error was. I found this explanation as well, that people might find useful: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-419284940